# Can a suspended thread be aborted?

Tags: multithreading, delphi-prism, oxygene

I created a thread and that thread can be suspended. So, how do I kill or terminate a suspended thread?

I tried to `ABORT` the thread and I got a runtime error message saying that the thread is suspended and it can't be aborted. I've looked for **terminate** method or something similar and it doesn't seem to exist.

```
myThread := new Thread(@BigLoop);
myThread.Start;

myThread.Suspend;
myThread.Abort; <<<===exception is raised.
```

So, how do you kill or terminate a suspended thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I resumed the suspended thread, I was able to abort the thread;

```
myThread := new Thread(@BigLoop);
myThread.Start;

myThread.Suspend;


if MyThread.ThreadState = ThreadState.Suspended then
   myThread.Resume;

myThread.Abort;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that it's unadvisable to use abort. A better solution would be to use a waithandle (autoresetevent/manualresetevent) to notify the thread that it should stop running. Remember that "Abort" doesn't work on anything that calls into native code, like com or pinvoke.

Comment: Ck. That's true but what if you are trying to abort a thread on your program shutdown. Does it matter then?